# Spring Boot Logger Aspects

Tags: java, spring, logging, aop, aspect

I'm having problems getting my logging aspect to log information when methods from classes of a particular package are accessed.  In other words, "no" logging occurs.  I even got desperate and added System.out.println statements, with no luck.

All of my classes are located under the **org.my.package** package, i.e. **org.my.package.controller**, **org.my.package.model**, etc.

Here is my Application class:

```
package org.my.package;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.my.package.config"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class FirstWebAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FirstWebAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my configuration class:

```
package org.my.package.config;

import org.deloitte.javatraining.daythree.utilities.MyLogger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.my.package.utilities"})
public class AssetConfig {

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Bean   
    public MyLogger myLogger(){
       return new MyLogger();
    }
}
```

This is my Aspect class:

```
package org.my.package.utilities;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyLogger {

    /** Handle to the log file */
    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public MyLogger () {}

    @AfterReturning("execution(* org.my.package.*.*(..))")
    public void logMethodAccessAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.info("***** Completed: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " *****");
        System.out.println("***** Completed: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " *****");
    }

    @Before("execution(* org.my.package.*.*(..))")
    public void logMethodAccessBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.info("***** Starting: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " *****");
        System.out.println("***** Starting: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " *****");
    }
}
```

These are my Gradle build dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile('com.h2database:h2:1.3.156')
    compile('javax.servlet:jstl:1.2')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
    providedRuntime("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") 
}
```

Am I missing something or otherwise mis-configuring my Aspect class?  I can't find anything wrong, after verifying with other, similar Stack Overflow questions and online tutorials.

Please advise.

Comment: You are currently only matching methods on classes in the `org.my.package` not sub packages. What you probably want is `execution( * org.my.package..*.*(..))` notice the `..` instead of `.`.

Comment: *face-palm*  Thanks!!  That was it.  Please reply with an answer, so I can give you credit for this question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your point cut, `execution( * org.my.package.*.*(..))`, is only matching the execution of methods on classes in the `org.my.package`package not sub packages.

What you probably want is `execution( * org.my.package..*.*(..))` notice the `..` instead of `.`.