# Spring Boot application context broken when adding AOP advices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I'm trying to use the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335563/spring-boot-logger-aspects), as base for my own AOP logging. However, when I add the advices, the application context no longer loads.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyLogger {

    /** Handle to the log file */
    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public MyLogger () {}

    @AfterReturning("execution(* org.my.package.*.*(..))")
    public void logMethodAccessAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.info("***** Completed: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " *****");
        System.out.println("***** Completed: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " *****");
    }

    @Before("execution(* org.my.package.*.*(..))")
    public void logMethodAccessBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.info("***** Starting: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " *****");
        System.out.println("***** Starting: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " *****");
    }
}
```

Exception stack, a whole bunch of `Could not autowire field`:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xxxxxx.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
```

`UserService` is a completely unrelated class, and everything runs again if I comment out the methods annotated with `@AfterReturning` and `@Before`.

AOP dependencies are there:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
```

Any idea why this happens? I don't even know where to start looking.

Comment: Does the `UserService` implement an interface?

Comment: @fateddy No, it doesn't... So I need to create interfaces for all beans in the package matched by the advices, in this case `org.my.package`, right?

Comment: No - you do not need to create interfaces for your beans. The problem could relate to how spring creates AOP proxies: JDK-Dynamic Proxies (default) vs. CGLIB Proxies. Enable CGLIB Proxying by adding  `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)` to one of your config-classes. See also this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35579802/4516887.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bean UserService is now a proxy and doesn't match the required type for injection.
Possible workaround:

- Create an interface UserService and a service class that implement the interface
- Enable CGLIB based proxy (@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true))
- Weave aspect at compile time.

Comment: It worked for me too, thanks for the question and answer, @JEY  , could you please refer me with some good documentation for Spring proxy and aop architecture with spring

Comment: @fateddy , please let me know the good documentation for spring proxy and aop